# Haskell - Weave two lists together in chunks of n size?

Tags: haskell

I am practicing some Haskell exam paper questions, and have come across the following

Define a Haskell function weaveHunks which takes an int and
two lists and weaves them together in hunks of the given size.
Be sure to declare its type signature.

Example:

weaveHunks 3 "abcdefghijklmno" "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"

=> "abcABCdefDEFghiGHIjklJKLmnoMNO"

I have found the following on Stack Overflow, which is just too weave two lists together but only in chunks of 1

```
weaveHunks :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks xs [] = xs
weaveHunks [] ys = ys
weaveHunks (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : weaveHunks xs ys
```

I am having problems adjusting this to take chunks fo n size, I am very new to Haskell but this is what I have so far

```
weaveHunks :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks n xs [] = xs
weaveHunks n [] ys = ys
weaveHunks n xs ys = (take n xs) : (take n ys) : weaveHunks n (drop n xs) (drop n ys)
```

I am getting an error on the last line

> (Couldn't match type `a' with`[a]')

Is `(drop n xs)` not a list?

Comment: The type of `weaveHunks` says it produces a `[a]`. If you leave out the type signature and load that up in ghci, what does it tell you the type is?

Comment: I removed the type signature and :t gave me 'weaveHunks :: p -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]'

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed something; you'll have to delete the first two lines to get that type info. Anyway, you got your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close!

By using the `:` operator to prepend the hunks, you're expressing that `take n xs` is one element of the result list, `take n ys` the next, and so on. But actually in both cases it's *multiple* elements you're prepending. That's the `[a]` that should actually be just `a`.

The solution is to use the `++` operator instead, which prepends an entire list rather than just a single element.

This is the full solution as I'd write it:

```
weaveHunks :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks _ xs [] = xs
weaveHunks _ [] ys = ys
weaveHunks n xs ys = xHunk ++ yHunk ++ weaveHunks n xRemain yRemain
 where [(xHunk, xRemain), (yHunk, yRemain)] = splitAt n <$> [xs,ys]
```

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. Can I ask also, what does <$> mean?

Comment: It’s fmap but as an infix operator. For lists, fmap = map for historical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

As @leftaroundabout said, since your appending lists of type `[a]`, you need to use `++` instead of `:`. With this in mind, your code would then look like this:

```
weaveHunks :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks _ xs [] = xs
weaveHunks _ [] ys = ys
weaveHunks n xs ys = (take n xs) ++ (take n ys) ++ weaveHunks n (drop n xs) (drop n ys)
```

If your interested, you can also use library functions to do this task:

```
import Data.List.Split

weaveHunks :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
weaveHunks n xs ys = concat $ zipWith (++) (chunksOf n xs) (chunksOf n ys)
```

**Note:** [`chunksOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) is from `Data.List.Split`, which splits the list into sublists of length `n`, so the type of this function is `Int -> [a] -> [[a]]`. [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) zips two lists based on a condition, in this case concatenation `++`. [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) turns a list of `[[a]]` into `[a]`.

Comment: have you tested your 2nd solution with two lists of radically different sizes? zip tends to cut off a dangling tail on size mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler (IMO) just to reverse the arguments

```
weaveHunks :: Int -> [a]  -> [a]  -> [a]
weaveHunks n xs ys = case splitAt n xs of
  ([],_)    -> ys
  (l1,l2)   -> l1 ++ weaveHunks n ys l2
```

or if you want to be super careful

```
weaveHunks :: Int -> [a]  -> [a]  -> [a]
weaveHunks n
    | n<=0          = error "bad block size"
    | otherwise     = go
  where
    go xs ys = case splitAt n xs of
      ([],_)    -> ys
      (l1,l2)   -> l1 ++ go ys l2
```

(It's easy to rewrite with `take` and `drop`, but this avoids duplicating the effort.  Either list can be infinite.)